# Why does Ethernet.begin() require a MAC address when WiFi.begin() doesn't?

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I am working on an Arduino application which is dependant on a certain library. This library uses the `Ethernet` class for network communications, but ideally, I would like it to be wireless (I have both an Ethernet and WiFi shield available for testing).

When working on replacing the [`Ethernet`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet) functionality of the library with the corresponding [`WiFi`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi) functionality, I noticed that the [`Ethernet.begin()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetBegin) function requires a MAC address while the [`WiFi.begin()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiBegin) doesn't (it instead accepts SSID and password, among a couple of other things).

As both come shipped with a MAC address sticker on them, I couldn't really figure out why this is the case (and if I need to supply the MAC address found on the WiFi shield in some other fashion).

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

The flip answer would be "because it doesn't need it…"

I think what is going on is that older Ethernet shields did not have a MAC address and it was necessary for the code to set one (and I would guess that on at least some of them you can still set the MAC address, overriding the one that is on the sticker).

WiFi cards, I would guess, are newer and the MAC address is always there, so there is no need to require you to assign it.

Comment: I *think* this is because [most] WiFi cards already have a firmware, which holds the MAC address and that's why [changing](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2005/09/how-to-change-mac-address-of-your.html) it on a WiFi card is only possible if the firmware allows it. With Ethernet there is no firmware needed, or simply put the Arduino *is* the firmware.